# Select unique set of activerecord objects from two arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two queries that return User records in my app, they look like the following:

```
alert_queue = scope(alert.player_id)    
all_queue = User.where(all_alerts: 1)
```

Both the `scope` method and obviously `User.where` returns user records.

My question is, is there anyway that I can merge these two arrays and only get unique user records. The same user might be returned for each query above and get listed twice if I merge the arrays as is. I'd like to get them unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add together the arrays and call `uniq` on it like so:

```
(alert_queue + all_queue).uniq
```

Here's a sample app showcasing an ActiveRecord example:

```
2.1.1 :014 > jeff = User.where(name: 'jeff')
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" = 'jeff'
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 6, name: "jeff", alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:32", updated_at: "2014-12-03 03:03:43">]>
2.1.1 :015 > alerts = User.where(alert: 5)
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."alert" = 5
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 2, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 3, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 4, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 5, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 6, name: "jeff", alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:32", updated_at: "2014-12-03 03:03:43">]>
2.1.1 :016 > jeff.count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."name" = 'jeff'
 => 1
2.1.1 :017 > alerts.count
   (0.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."alert" = 5
 => 6
2.1.1 :018 > (jeff + alerts).uniq.count
 => 6
2.1.1 :019 > (jeff + alerts).uniq
 => [#<User id: 6, name: "jeff", alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:32", updated_at: "2014-12-03 03:03:43">, #<User id: 1, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 2, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 3, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 4, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">, #<User id: 5, name: nil, alert: 5, created_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11", updated_at: "2014-12-03 02:50:11">]
```

Comment: That works on primitive values. Will it work on ActiveRecord objects?